# TypefaceJS site down / need help converting

Tags: three.js, typeface.js

Can anyone help me convert two type faces to typeFace.js code. The site seems down or no longer in service.

Font types
univers 67 condensed Bold 14pt
Novecento Light Wide / Light Wide 53pt
Novecento Light Wide / Light Wide 18pt

Let me know thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/ is another convertor for typeface.js.

PS: I'm the author of facetype.js